# Trying to sum array of strings

Tags: javascript

Have an array of quotes (quotes), need to find the average length of one particular person's quotes (name).

I can find the values, but do not know how to get the sum of the returned values

```
let averageQuoteLength = (name) => {
   i = crewMembers.indexOf(name)
   a=(-1);
   while (a  <= quotes[i].length) {
     a++
     console.log(quotes[i][a].length)
 }
}
```

Comment: Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: can you share the structure of your quotes array so that we can have a better understanding of the problem?

Comment: you are not returning the `a` value.

Comment: You need to define the variable before using—>. Let a = -1.  Then return a after the loop

Answer (score 0):

assumes you have a 2 dimensional array more or less like:

```
var quotes = [
  ['quote1', 'quote2', 'quote3'],
  ['quote1', 'quote2', 'quote3'],
  ['quote1', 'quote2', 'quote3']
]
```

and some crewMembers array that has all names at the corresponding indices

try this out:

```
let averageQuoteLength = (name) => {
  let i = crewMembers.indexOf(name);
  return (quotes[i].reduce((acc, val) => acc += val.length, 0) / quotes[i].length);
};
```

the array reduce method sums all the length of all quotes in the array at quotes[i], and then I divide by the length of the array to get the average quote length. Reduce is a useful tool worth learning.